# What is the const char **envp supposed to do?

Tags: c, environment-variables

My issue is that I don't understand one particular line of code

I was reverse engineering a crackme when this envp argument appeared on main and then the program started using it afterwards which made me not understand how to solve the second part of the crackme (I was using c decompiler to analyze the password of the crackme). I still solved the crackme with patching binary but I don't understand what this line means and it is bugging me....

```
int __cdecl main(int argc, const char **argv, const char **envp){
  char *Format; // [esp+0h] [ebp-98h]
  char v5; // [esp+20h] [ebp-78h]

  _alloca((size_t)Format);
  __main();
  printf("IOLI Crackme Level 0x06\n");
  printf("Password: ");
  scanf("%s", &v5);
  check(&v5, (int)envp);
  return 0;
} 

int __cdecl check(char *Str, int a2){
  size_t v2; // eax
  char Src; // [esp+1Bh] [ebp-Dh]
  unsigned int i; // [esp+1Ch] [ebp-Ch]
  int v6; // [esp+20h] [ebp-8h]
  int v7; // [esp+24h] [ebp-4h]

  v6 = 0;
  for ( i = 0; ; ++i ){
    v2 = strlen(Str);
    if ( i >= v2 )
      break;
    Src = Str[i];
    sscanf(&Src, "%d", &v7);
    v6 += v7;
    if ( v6 == 16 )
      parell(Str, a2);}
  return printf("Password Incorrect!\n");
}

int *__cdecl parell(char *Src, int a2){
  int *result; // eax
  int i; // [esp+10h] [ebp-8h]
  int v4; // [esp+14h] [ebp-4h]

  sscanf(Src, "%d", &v4);
  result = (int *)dummy(v4, a2);
  if ( result )
  {
    for ( i = 0; i <= 9; ++i ){
      if ( !(v4 & 1) ){
        printf("Password OK!\n");
        exit(0);
      }
      result = &i;
    }
  }
  return result;
}

signed int __cdecl dummy(int a1, int a2)
{
  int v2; // ecx
  int v5; // [esp+14h] [ebp-4h]

  v5 = 0;
  while ( *(_DWORD *)(4 * v5 + a2) )            // 1 == True
  {
    v2 = 4 * v5++;                              //  4 or 0
    if ( !strncmp(*(const char **)(v2 + a2), "LOLO", 3u) )
      return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

It goes from main to check to parallel (if you fullfil the condition correctly, and then to dummy which creates an infinite loop except: if //!strncmp(*(const char **)(v2 + a2), "LOLO", 3u) == 1 and the problem is i //don't understand what the a2 means which comes from this envp variable in //main)

This is the hint from the solutions, as I said I am stuck on the second condition (the infinite loop on):
Level 0x06: same algorithm as in 5, but envp LOLO=1

Comment: This parameter const char **envp supplies pointer to an array of pointers to environment variables.

Comment: so in this case what does it mean ( i think the main implication of the envp variable is found on the main function , as we see later it becomes a2) . I dont really understand your answer(supplies pointer to an array of pointers to environment variables) , does it have a value based on something? Sorry if i sound naive but i just started reverse engineering ( i had no clue what environment variables where before i saw them in this example).

Comment: In fact it is similar to argv but supplies environment variables of the OS. It is an implementation defined declaration of main.

Comment: so why in this case the hint say envp LOLO = 1? This is my main issue. And i dont want to ask too much but if you know can you give me a valid password i can pass as i said the first part with a password like 97 or 88 but it gets stack on the infinite loop in the function dummy. And how does this line connect with what you said before (check(&v5, (int)envp);)?

Comment: I am sorry. I did not investigate your code. So I can not answer the qyestion.

Comment: well if i understand 70 percent of this code it will be a piece of cake for you , if you find a password just let me know , thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

> What is the const char **envp supposed to do?

As @Vlad told you in comments, it `envp` is analogous to `argv`, but rather than program arguments it conveys the process's environment variables to it.  These are the same key / value pairs that can be accessed via the `getenv()` function or set via the `putenv()` function.  The process receives them from its parent, usually by simply inheriting a copy of its parent's environment.  Shells have a user interface for manipulating these; for example, in `bash` one might use the command `LOLO=1` to set an environment variable named "LOLO", which need not previously have existed, to the value "1".  Windows shells have different syntax for the same thing.

If you analyze the code you've presented, you'll see that `envp` is simply passed (as an `int`) through several levels of function until ultimately it is used (only) in `dummy()`.  And you'll note further that `dummy()` does not use its *other* argument -- all it does is analyze the data to which its second argument (converted back to a pointer) points.  In particular, it looks like it is scanning through the environment, looking for any environment variable whose name begins with "LOL" -- if it finds one, then it returns 1, and otherwise it returns 0.  This explains the hint you asked about: it is not sufficient to figure out the password; *no* password is accepted unless an appropriate environment variable is set (to anything). "LOLO" would be the name of such a variable.

The actual password checking is in functions `check` and `parell`.  The former performs a pre-check for decimal digits in the password string adding up digit-wise to 16.  If that's ever satisfied (even if that happens before the end of the password)  then it hands off the whole password to function `parell` for further testing.  Here is where the environment check is performed, and if that passes then the leading decimal digits of the password are converted to a number, and as long as that number is even, the password is accepted.

Supposing, then, that the decompiler did its job accurately, there are numerous passwords that would be accepted, so long as that environment variable is set:

```
88
4444
23452
```

including some that exploit quirks in the parsing performed by `check` and `parell`, such as

```
0d79
2pwned!!
```

Also, it looks like the password input in `main()` is subject to a buffer overflow, so you might be able to go at the problem from that totally different direction.

Comment: well i have solved the quiz patching the memory but this is not about solving the problem but understanding it(for me). So all of these passwords fail and they all seem to fail in the dummy in which an infinite loop is created. The reason why this happes(at least this is what i get) is because the while is true no matter what and the only way to get out is to get to the return 1, the issue is in order to get to the return one you need the if to be true and in order for that to be true you need v2 and a2. From my understanding v2 is either 4 or 0 and a2 has created this whole mess with the envp

Comment: btw just asking how can i wright replies with more than 600 characters? As i said if we trace back the a2 it leads as to the envp which i dont know its value i understand what you both saying but that doesnt solve me the problem. So from my perspective there are 2 cenarios , either the decompiler failed or there is something that we have  not understood. As for the solution with buffer overflow i am not in that level yet so i am not in a position to talk about it.

Comment: If anyone wants the files the link is here: https://github.com/Maijin/Workshop2015/tree/master/IOLI-crackme and i am reffering to the crackme 6 I decompiled it with IDA in assembly and in c.

Comment: @konstantians, I emphasize again that the program does not accept ***any*** password unless it finds an appropriate environment variable in its runtime environment.  *All* of the passwords given work for me in a program I re-compiled from the de-compiled code, as long as that environment variable is set.  Moreover, I see no reason in the decompiled code to expect an infinite loop.

Comment: Yea i can get behind that. So what is the right environment how do i find it( i agree the password you gave me , are partially correct). The reason why i am talking about an infinite loop is based on the IDA debugger it get stack in the while ... if . And then i think after a lot of times executing the loop( i dont know why, 40+ loops)it returns 0 which doesnt get us to the right password because we need 1.At least this is what i get. So as i said before how do we set the appropriate environment variable in its runtime environment.Again sorry if i sound stupid i am a newbie.

Comment: @konstantians, a 40-iteration loop sounds most likely to be the loop over environment variables.  There very well could be 40 or more of them.  This answer already discusses what the program is looking for in its environment-variable search.  How you actually provide such a variable depends on your platform and on how you launch the program.